# Initialize fields of user-defined `types` in arbitrary order

Tags: types, constructor, julia

I'd like to know if it is possible to initialize the fields of a user-defined `type` (or `struct`) in a deliberate order by using the field names  so that the order of defined variables in the code does not matter. In other words, my question is about using keywords in an `inner` or `outer` `constructor`.

I have something like the following snippet in mind, where the order of initialization of fields is opposite to the order of their appearance in the code:

```
# Julia ver. 0.4.7

type MyType
    x1
    x2

    MyType(y) = new(x2 = y, x1 = 0)  # inner constructor
end

MyType(a, b) = new(x2 = a, x1 = b)  # outer constructor
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/initialize-fields-of-user-defined-types-in-arbitrary-order/8109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative answer, you can also make use of the `Parameters.jl` package:

```
using Parameters

@with_kw struct Foo
    x::Int = 1
    y::Float64 = 2.0
end

# now the following code works
Foo(x=3, y=4.)
Foo(y=5.)
```

There are *no* performance penalties. The `Parameters.jl` package basically does the same trick explained in Alexander Morley's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48061491) with some extra features like default values for the fields.

Comment: are there any performance implications for such a `struct` using `with_kw` macro and keyword?

Comment: No performance penalties. The package basically does the same trick explained in Alexander's answer with some extra features like default values for the fields.

Comment: And as far as I remember from GitHub's comments, at some point Parameters.jl will be part of Julia as well, but someone can correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like the below. This would work even nicer with [NamedTuples](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/22194) coming in 0.7. (NB: this is just an idea you would probably want to add some checks/optimizations).

```
struct Foo
       x
       y
end

function Foo(;kwargs...)
           kwargnames = [x[1] for x in kwargs]
           Foo([kwargs[findfirst(kwargnames,i)][2] for i in fieldnames(Foo)]...)
ends

Foo(x=10,y=20) == Foo(y=20,x=10)
```

Comment: could you please explain your code snippet? I am still a novice in Julia.